# Postgresql add existing column to composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql with a composite primary key. The primary key consists of two columns named:

```
DATETIME, UID
```

I have a another (non-null) column named ACTION already existing in this table. How do I add ACTION to the composite primary key? Ie: I'd like the resulting primary key of the table to be the triplet:

```
DATETIME, UID, ACTION
```

Comment: You need drop and re-create the PK constraint

Comment: @horse Thanks. How do I find the name of the constraint - does it have a standardized name such as tablename_pkey which would enable automation, or must I manually deduce it from some kind of query related to the table?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First drop the primary key constraint.  You can get the name of the constraint by typing

```
\d my_table
```

and look under indexes for something like:

```
"my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (datetime, uid)
```

Drop it by doing:

```
alter table my_table drop constraint my_table_pkey;
```

Then create the new composite primary key by doing:

```
alter table my_table add constraint my_table_pkey primary key (datetime, uid, action);
```

Comment: In a transaction!

Comment: What if there other tables depend on it?